# How to add Postgres extensions via .sh file

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I'm trying to add extensions for Postgres by writing the following script (setup.sh):

```
sudo -u postgres psql my_database
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```

when I do vagrant up, it supposed to run and add extensions automatically by running the script. However, I got the error message that

```
==> default: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "exit"
==> default: LINE 1: exit
==> default:         ^
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 24: CREATE: command not found
```

Please note that I have installed all the necessary postgres stuff to run the code above. In addition, when I enter these command manually, it successfully creates the extension. Thanks to whoever that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
sudo -u postgres psql my_database -c "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack"
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> -c command
>
> --command=command
>
> Specifies that psql is to execute the given command string, command.

also consider using `-f sql_file.sql` for more complicated scripts, or smth like:

```
psql <<EOF
\x
SELECT NOW();
SELECT * FROM foo;
EOF
```